# javascript check if string has one of set of chars

Tags: javascript

I am implementing password complexity checks, one of the requirement is that the password contain at least one of a set of chars.

How would I code an efficient function for that, ie

```
function hasOneOfChars(s, chars) {
  // assuming both s and chars are strings, 
  // return true iff s has at least one char from chars
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you explain more? About the input and output

Comment: `return [...chars].some(char => s.includes(char))`

Comment: Tryong to force users to increase password security like this, actually lowers it. More people will choose `Password1` because you force them to

Comment: Jonas it's windows password complexity requirements in my case not my choice

Comment: CertainPerformance can you write an answer so I can approve it ?

Comment: Explain more, this is nothing ... and you made 0 effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(credit goes to CertainPerformance)

```js
// assuming both s and chars are strings, return true iff s has at least one char from chars
function hasOneOfChars(s, chars) {
  return [...chars].some(char => s.includes(char));
}

console.log(hasOneOfChars('aaabbb', 'ax'));
console.log(hasOneOfChars('aaabbb', 'xy'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using above function Try using it with regex pattern.

- Contain at least 8 characters
- contain at least 1 number
- contain at least 1 lowercase character (a-z)
- contain at least 1 uppercase character (A-Z)
- contains only 0-9a-zA-Z

if you want set of chars use below pattern, Moreover {4,} is atleast contain charaters so you can change according to your requirement

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By requirement to receive 2 strings arguments. You can try the following code.

```js
function hasOneOfChars(s, chars) {
 for (let char of chars.split(""))
  if (s.indexOf(char) > -1) {
   return true;
  }
 return false;
}

console.log(hasOneOfChars("abcd", "abcasjkdf"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could sort both strings and do the following :

```
var s = "ytreza".split("").sort().join("");
var chars = "ytrewq".split("").sort().join("");
hasOneOfChars(s, chars); // true

function hasOneOfChars (s, chars) {
  var a, b, i, n;
  if (s < chars) a = s, b = chars;
  else a = chars, b = s;
  i = 0, n = a.length;
  while (i < n && a[i] !== b[0]) i++;
  return i < n;
}
```

Using sorted strings you don't have to loop through both strings anymore :

```
a = "azerty"
b = "qwerty"
n = a.length // 6
i = 0, a[i] === b[0] ? false
i = 1, a[i] === b[0] ? false
i = 2, a[i] === b[0] ? true
return i < n // true
```